# A HREF Content in XML not loaded as link when dynamically generated using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, xml, hyperlink, anchor

I have an XML file which contains some Anchor(A HREFs) tags in the XML child tags.... when I am loading the content using JQuery and generating dynamic HTML elements then links dont appear.

Sample XML Tag:

```
<question>
    <number>12</number>
    <qts>How can I download the mobile app?</qts>
    <ans>Please login to the site – <a href="https://google.com">https://google.com</a> from your desktop/laptop. Go to the subscribe page and download the file that is appropriate for you.</ans> 
</question>
```

JQuery Tag Loading:

```
xml_ans = $(this).find('ans').text();
```

The Problem is https://google.com does not appear as a link.

Could any one please throw some light or hints on it?

Comment: The content now appears as a link... I forgot this concept... when you add data, the content is processed as a HTML else if you dont add CDATA tag then the content is processed as plain text...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your HTML in your XML with `<![CDATA[ ]]>`;

```
<question>
        <number>12</number>
        <qts>How can I download the mobile app?</qts>
        <ans>
                <![CDATA[
                    Please login to the site – <a href="https://google.com">https://google.com</a> from your desktop/laptop. Go to the subscribe page and download the file that is appropriate for you.
                ]]>
        </ans>  
</question>
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA

Comment: Not working I tried to put <a> in CDATA but it shows it as a string value not  as a link